# How to define / build up a coding framework?

Tags: pmi-framework

In my company, we develop web applications and CMS and websites.

We are having a lot of problems because every programmer codes as he wants and it is too hard for the others to maintain them, so we'd like to define a common [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) to be adopted across the whole company.

I believe our framework should match the following:

1. The base should be [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)
2. The method should be Code-First
3. The standards should be Naming Convention
4. The type should be 3 layer programming
5. The method should be [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
6. We should use from our dll archive
7. The UI should be with HTML and CSS
8. And using from Bootstrap

The problem is that I don't know where to start. Could you help me?

Comment: I think this is more to do with architectural problem and not related to project management. Practices can be standardized but what should go in the standardization is purely Tech-Arch question.

Comment: Even after rephrasing the question, it still sounds off-topic for a PM + too broad for a single answer...

Comment: I believe this is a multi-tier problem, and the solution could be driven by PMs by understanding the problems and addressing it the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you're having multiple problems and trying to solve them at once.
It never seems easy to get programmers to leave their egos outside and act as a single "team"/"company" entity while creating code in the name of that entity.

The easiest thing you can start with is to put automated checks in for [coding standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions). There are many tools out there for most languages. The abstract term you'll be looking for is [static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis).Such tools require you to create a ruleset from which they work, and verify the code against. Such checks, like "no method should be more than 9 lines" or "no class should have more than 5 public methods" and "only tabs are allowed for line start" make sure that the code *looks* the same. Most likely these simple checks will drive a somewhat better design as the programmers will need to come up with solutions to adhere to the standards. 
Introducing this usually creates a huge roar, as it is a straight offence against the egos.

The second problem you're trying to solve is consequent design. That's something a highly respected (!important) technical personnel could drive. Obviously the best scenario is to have a team who's self-aware and wants to do the best possible work, but judging from your question this is not a given in your situation. In such setup, you need this senior member (architect, tech lead, you name it) to have enough power in his hands to make the others do what he thinks would fit. On the other hand, he should avoid using that tool with all means possible and try to lead by example and convert the others. Pair with them, teach them and make them see why they should behave differently.

The third problem is the technology stack.

I believe that if you put things like that into stone, you might end up using the wrong tool for a particular job. I'd rather have a rule of: "Assess the tools available before each new task, and see what's the best for it".
You might find that for some tasks MVC is overkill when a simple static webpage would be enough. Or you might find that there are way better tools than Bootstrap. You won't be able to respond to technological shifts in the industry if you have a hard policy on tools used.

To cut it short: it's more wise to "grow" a team than to rule them. Sure, they require borders, but try explaining those in the form of visions, goals and team values that they all should align to while they find their own comfortable way of solving your business needs.
"Hard-wiring" implementation(=tools, design) regulations on the other hand will set you up for a rigid and fragile process.

Comment: I believe you're spot on with the third problem. These situations can indeed lead to situations where smart people are locked in to using X person's favorite tool, which might be okay in certain situations but stifles innovation in others.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a solutions architect. Some of what you mention are coding conventions and could be documented (a wiki works well for this). The role of an solutions architect is also to define non-functional requirements, such as what technologies are used (Bootstrap, MVC, etc).

Simon Brown has some great training material and [books published](https://leanpub.com/software-architecture-for-developers?utm_campaign=software-architecture-for-developers&utm_medium=embed&utm_source=www.codingthearchitecture.com) around this area. I would recommend understanding the role of a solutions architect, talk with your team about the importance of the role and either promote or hire someone to fulfill that function.